# How can i get the second to last element of a Sequence? Clojure

Tags: clojure, sequence

i know how to get the last element with the function last but is it possible to get the second to last element of a Sequence?

```
(defn last
  [args]
   (last args))
(last [1 2 3 4]) ;;--> 4 but i want it to return 3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [reverse](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reverse), [take-last](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/take-last), [butlast](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/butlast) or [nth](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/nth) (this one seems to be the fastest):

```
(defn second-to-last1 [s]
  (second (reverse s)))

(second-to-last1 (range 100))
=> 98

(defn second-to-last2 [s]
  (first (take-last 2 s)))

(second-to-last2 (range 100))
=> 98

(defn second-to-last3 [s]
  (last (butlast s)))

(second-to-last3 (range 100))
=> 98

(defn second-to-last4 [s]
  (nth s (- (count s) 2) nil))

(second-to-last4 (range 100))
=> 98
```

Comment: if the input is vector, it could also be `(peek (pop [1 2 3 4 5 6]))`